# Laravel 5 middleware Auth check not working

Tags: php, redirect, laravel-5, infinite-loop, middleware

i want to show a 404 error page if the user try to access to de admin page if he is not logged or if he dont have the 'Admin' type. This work fine if the user is logged in, if not the user access to the admin panel. If i remove the `if(Auth::check())` the script shows a `Trying to get property of non-object` error.

```
class AdminMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if ($request->user()->type != 'Admin'){
                return abort(404);
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
class AdminMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if ($request->user()->type != 'Admin'){
                return abort(404);
            }
        }else{
            return abort(404);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It should check if user is logged in and if so check if hes and admin, if hes not logged in show him the 404

or a shorter version

```
class AdminMiddleware {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check() && $request->user()->type == 'Admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I forgot to put the else in the Auth::check().